# VS Code can't find malloc.c

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-code, linux-mint

I'm getting an eror when I include `cstdlib` in C++.

> Unable to open 'malloc.c': File not found (file:///build/glibc-bfm8X4/glibc-2.23/malloc/malloc.c).

The error comes from the top part of the VS code window.
[image: error source]

(the error occurs during debugging.)

Here's some of the code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <portaudio.h>

//...

static int paCallback( const void *inputBuffer, void *outputBuffer,
                           unsigned long framesPerBuffer,
                           const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo* timeInfo,
                           PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags,
                           void *userData )
{
    /* Cast data passed through stream to our structure. */
    paTestData *data = (paTestData*)userData; 
    float *out = (float*)outputBuffer;
    unsigned int i;
    (void) inputBuffer; /* Prevent unused variable warning. */

    for( i=0; i<framesPerBuffer; i++ )
    {
        *out++ = data->left_phase;  /* left */
        *out++ = data->right_phase;  /* right */

        float currentSample = 0;
        char *sampleData = new char[4];

        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            sampleData[j] = currentBuffer[&currentIndex + j];
        }

        currentSample = (float)atof(sampleData); //cstdlib is included to use atof

        //gets audio sample data and forwards to PortAudio
        data->left_phase = currentSample;
        data->right_phase = currentSample;

        currentIndex += 4;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using Linux Mint 81.1 if that helps.

Comment: How exactly do you include it? Can you copy the code?

Comment: Please, at a minimum, post a [mcve].

Comment: I edited the question to include some code. Hope that helps.

Comment: Please add the command line you are using and the exact error message. Merely including `<cstdlib>` should not cause *"Unable to open malloc.c:..."*.

Comment: You've caused a crash within the memory-managing code and the debugger is looking for the source code for whatever function you made crash. It's normal to not have this file.

Comment: `currentBuffer[&currentIndex + j]` looks extremely suspicious, by the way. What is `currentBuffer`?

Comment: `currentBuffer` is the data from the cuurently playing audio file in `char`s.

Comment: Yes but what is `&currentIndex`? Is it really a valid index?

Comment: If currentBuffer and currentIndex are not objects with crazy overloaded operators, `currentBuffer[&currentIndex + j]` shouldn't ever compile.

Comment: Learn to use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Answer (score 1):

I encounter the same problem. The problem is that I did not compile the cpp file with debug flag -g.........When I re-compile the cpp file containing malloc and reinterpret_cast, the problem disappeared.
But I am wrong. The true solution is not to step the line that malloc is in, other wise, the source file of malloc.c is needed.
cf, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/811#issuecomment-559085447

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this in the follow way ..
my error is
"Unable to open 'libc-start.c': File not found (file:///build/glibc-OTsEL5/glibc-2.27/csu/libc-start.c"
so I make a dir in the root directory

```
$cd /
$sudo mkdir build
$cd build
$sudo mkdir glibc-OTsEL5
$cd glibc-OTsEL5
```

and then download the glibc from internet

```
$sudo wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.27.tar.gz
```

then unpack it

```
$sudo tar -xzvf glibc-2.27.tar.gz
```

every thing seems to be ok

This solution is taken from https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/811#issuecomment-406544778